# /etc/rc.local being executed twice

Tags: boot, startup

Since ugrading from 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04.1 I've noticed my /etc/rc.local gets executed twice (within a second of each other) on boot. Any ideas why?

I've noticed in syslog what might be a clue, that being two slightly different preambles to the file being run which is making me think rc.local is being called from two places?

***Jan  9 21:08:59 rugrat systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist...***
[...]
Jan  9 21:09:00 rugrat rc.local[949]: Various logging output relating to the file being run
[...]
***Jan  9 21:09:01 rugrat systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...***
[...]
Jan  9 21:09:00 rugrat rc.local[949]: Various logging output relating to the file being run
[...]

Or is that a red herring?

Comment: Typical - I found nothing from a Google search until posting my question... Then I find it has already been reported as a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1895424). Any ideas how best to remove the duplicate execution?

Comment: Rewrite your `/etc/rc.local` to check if an action has been done, before doing it.  Or, consider using a flag file in `/var/run/` or some other directory that doesn't survive reboots.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator for the suggestion. I did consider something similar but felt like it was treating the symptom rather than the cause. I instead opted to disable one of the two services that was executing /etc/rc.local with ***systemctl disable rc.local.service*** and having rebooted can confirm the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

(1) systemctl status rc.local.service
rc.local.service - LSB: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rc.local; generated)
(2) systemctl status rc-local.serivce
rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
└─debian.conf

- If two services are enabled then twice /etc/rc.local is getting executed.